# Translate a json dictionary object to Array of objects

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I am getting back JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1650287883,
  "base":"EUR",
  "date":"2022-04-18",
  "rates":{
    "USD":1.080065,
    "EUR":1,
    "JPY":136.717309,
    "GBP":0.828707,
    "AUD":1.465437,
    "CAD":1.363857
  }
}
```

I was expecting rates to be an array, but it's an object. The currency codes may vary. Is there a way to Decode this with Swift's built-in tools?

I'm certain this won't work:

```
struct ExchangeRateResponse: Decodable {
    let success: Bool
    let base: String
    let date: Date
    let rates: [[String: Double]]

    private enum ResponseKey: String, CodingKey {
        case success, base, date, rates
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ResponseKey.self)

        success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
        base = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .base)
        date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        rates = try container.decode([[String: Double]].self, forKey: .rates)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io

Comment: `let rates: [[String: Double]]`, no point in having an array of dictionaries instead of one dictionary, `let rates: [String: Double]`. Of course the best solution is to convert it into an array of custom fx rates objects.

Comment: Duh… hello. Don't know what I was thinking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your model is wrong. you can do this:

```
struct YourModelName {
    let success: Bool
    let timestamp: Int
    let base, date: String
    let rates: [String: Double]
}
```

after that you can try do decode it.
something like this:

```
do {
   let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
   let loadData = try jsonDecoder.decode(YourModelName.self, from: data!)
   // 'loadData' is your data that you want. for your problem you have to use 'loadData.rates'. Hint: you have to use it in 'for' loop!
   DispatchQueue.main.async { _ in
       // if you have to update your UI
   }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot decode `date` to `Date` out of the box, but you can decode `timestamp` to `Date`.

Second of all it's impossible to decode a dictionary to an array. This is like *apples and oranges*.

But fortunately you can ***map*** the dictionary to an array because it behaves like an array (of tuples) when being mapped.

Just create an other struct `Rate`

```
struct Rate {
    let code: String
    let value: Double
}

struct ExchangeRateResponse: Decodable {
    let success: Bool
    let timestamp: Date
    let base: String
    let date: String
    let rates: [Rate]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case success, base, timestamp, date, rates
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
        timestamp = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .timestamp)
        base = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .base)
        date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)

        let rateData = try container.decode([String: Double].self, forKey: .rates)
        rates = rateData.map(Rate.init)
    }
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    let result = try decoder.decode(ExchangeRateResponse.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Or still shorter if you map the dictionary **after** decoding the stuff

```
struct ExchangeRateResponse: Decodable {
    let success: Bool
    let timestamp: Date
    let base: String
    let date: String
    let rates: [String:Double]
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    let result = try decoder.decode(ExchangeRateResponse.self, from: data)
    let rates = result.rates.map(Rate.init)
    print(rates)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```